# How can I find and install libXtst.so.6 in Centos 7 for scenebuilder-8.3.0-1.x86_64

Tags: centos, package-management, eclipse

I have a problem with this library: libXtst.so.6. I work with the eclipse IDE and I want to install scenebuilder-8.3.0-1.x86_64 for Drag and Drop UI in eclipse. When I enter this commend to install scenebuilder

```
rpm -ihv scenebuilder-8.3.0-1.x86_64
```

terminal gives me this error:

> error: Failed dependencies:
>
> libXtst.so.6 is needed by scenebuilder-8.3.0-1.x86_64

I don't know what it needs of me, but I downloaded and installed libXtst-1.2.2-2.1.el7.x86_64.rpm, but it doesn't work!

Comment: It gives me this error: There are no enabled repos. Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have. You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of downloading the RPM, you can try installing it from the CentOS repositories with the following (as root):

```
yum install libXtst
```

That should pull in any other dependencies and update any packages that require that.

If the 64-bit package is already installed then you may need to install the 32-bit library

```
yum install libXtst.i686
```

Comment: Thank you I think its work bcuase installed.but when I  type scenebuilder in terminal dosent run anything of sowftware  why?

Comment: Please amend your question to include further details regarding your new issue. For example, what happens when you execute scenebuilder? Can you copy the error message to your original question?

Answer (score 0):

Try `yum` instead of `rpm`. It will resolve dependencies for you:

```
yum reinstall http://download.gluonhq.com/scenebuilder/8.3.0/install/linux/scenebuilder-8.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: I dont now why Doesnt work 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Cannot open file: http://download.gluonhq.com/scenebuilder/8.3.0/install/linux/scenebuilder-8.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do